# Git detects ODBC Connection String exposed within my GitHub repository

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, security, github

I have already *pushed my code* to the `master` branch to the Git repo. But I forgot to secure of my connection database server setting.

In detail, I commited and pushed entirely local `appsettings.json` file that include ODBC connection string, secret keys, password of server.
I knew it is one of the most mistake of developers. But I worked hard to finish another piece of code, then cannot handle the whole problem.

According my research, Git was structured as worktree and each commit is a snapshot of the whole repo, so if I fix my mistake on locally code and push again, the problem cannot be solved the secret leak. Because Git saved my secret key & password on history. So I really need your help!

How can I solve the problem without modifiied actions to repository *(delete entire repo and create new one)*

And how to set up Git to against secured files when I just need to remove secret character strings and password on each commit?

> I am using **.NetCore** and **EntityFrameWork** to build a web api on *visual studio**.

Comment: For a start, change your account passwords and consider strengthening your account passwords such as the SA or equivalent. Web apps should be using an account that only has as much access as they need, not running as admin. Databases should also be protected by a whitelist allowing connections only from your known web servers, never from unknown endpoints. If you or some other admin needs access then it should be behind a VPN where you remote into one domain endpoint /w 2FA etc. and access the server/database via that.

Comment: Thank you very much ,@StevePy! I appreciate your advises. I found out the solution that recommend to use `git filter-branch` to rewrite git history. But it so many steps for accomplishment. Do you have any comment for my way?